# SQL Server database project for incremental changes

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I am working on a project where I need to update the databases such as update, insert etc on each release. Currently, I am using SQL files for it. If I want to use SQL Server database project of VS then how can I do incremental changes in it?

For example, insert statements which are included in the first release are not required for next release and so on. How to manage SQL Server database project in these scenarios. Do we need to delete those manually, but it may lose those scripts. Please share the best practices for these scenarios.

Comment: What sort of data are you referring to? If prerequisite data are required for the app to function (e.g. OrderStatus table), a common practice with SSDT is to use a `MERGE` script for each table that's executed in a post deployment script. That will allow you to deploy a new database (e.g. for isolated unit testing) or to upgrade an existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redgate is a good solution, although it's not free. It can use your favorite source control system (probably but not necessarily git) to track changes to tables, views, stored procedures, and all database object, and it has support for migration scripts as well. You wouldn't use a VS database project with RedGate, however. You just create objects (tables, views, etc.) in a SQL Sever instance and Redgate does the rest.